# How to write this JS function in best(smartest) way?

Tags: javascript

I would like to write the function which takes file size in bytes(7762432) and return value in user readable format (7,762,432 bytes).

```
function(fileSizeBytes){
    // mind blowing logic :)
    return userReadable;
}
```

I have done it using old school string split way, but i am just curious if there exist way that can blow my head and make me scream with "O god it can be done this way too !!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function addCommas(value) {
    var regex = /^(\d+)(\d{3}[\.]?.*)$/;
    while (regex.exec(value)) {
        value= RegExp.$1
                ? RegExp.$1 + ',' + RegExp.$2
                : RegExp.$2;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

one line function:

```
function formatFileSizeBytes(size) {
    return size.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$1,");
}
```

some testing:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= "123456789".split('').length; i++) {  
    alert(formatFileSizeBytes(a.slice(0,i).join(''))); 
}
```

Comment: Never used `(?=` before. Really clever solution! +1

Comment: thx; positive lookahead when available let write some very nice one-liners like this one.

Comment: Nice! The next thing is to make it locale-aware (as `,` might be `.` in, say, Germany).

Comment: var a = "123456789".split(''); for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) { alert(formatFileSizeBytes(a.slice(0,i).join(''))); } // testing code may be shorter ;-)

Comment: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m95qD/)** or [kiriliod's DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m95qD/1/)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, other countries also may have another digit grouping.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
function(fileSizeBytes){
    return fileSizeBytes.toString(10).split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(...)/g,'$1,').replace(/,$/,'').split('').reverse().join('') + ' bytes';
}
```

Comment: I've written almost the same function yesterday :-D /(...)/ will work incorrectly on 123, 123456, 123456789 and so on. Use /(...)(?=.)/ and then you may omit second replace.

Comment: I already did another `.replace(/,$/,'')`, but thanks for that, made it a lot shorter! :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there should be some [ENTERPRISE](http://enterprise-js.com/) solution for this with intensive i18n support

```
var numberLocaleFormat = (function() {
  var cache = {};
  return (function (separator, grouping, groupingAdd) {
    separator = separator || ",";
    grouping = grouping || 3;
    groupingAdd = groupingAdd || grouping;
    var key = grouping + "+" + groupingAdd + "/" + separator;
    if (key in cache) return cache[key];
    return (cache[key] = function(number){
      var str = [], number = number.toString();
      var separatorIndex = grouping;
      for (var i = number.length-1, idx = 0; i >= 0; i--, idx++) {
        str.push(number.charAt(i));
        if ((idx == separatorIndex-1) && i) {
           separatorIndex += groupingAdd;
           str.push(separator);
        }
      }
      return str.reverse().join('');
    });
  });
})();
```

Usage:

```
numberLocaleFormat()(1234578); // "12,345,678", America
numberLocaleFormat(" ")(12345678); // "12 345 678", Europe
numberLocaleFormat(",",4)(12345678); // "1234,5678", Japan
numberLocaleFormat(",", 3, 2)(12345678); // "1,23,45,678", India
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function four years ago:

```
function formatNumber(x) { 
    if(!isFinite(x)) return x.toString();
    var str         = Math.abs(x).toString();
    if(str.indexOf("e") != -1) return x.toString();
    var decimalPos  = str.indexOf(".");
    var decimal;

    if(decimalPos == -1)
        decimal = "";
    else {
        decimal = str.substring(decimalPos);
        str = str.substring(0, decimalPos);
    }
    if(str.length < 4) return x.toString();

    var start = str.substr(0, str.length % 3);
    if(start.length != 0) {
        str = str.substr(start.length)
        start += ",";
    }
    if(x < 0) start = "-" + start;

    var segments = new Array(Math.ceil(str.length / 3.0));
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 3) {
        segments[i / 3] = str.substr(i, 3);
    }

    return start + segments.join() + decimal;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer and Firefox, you can do `return Number(fileSizeBytes).toLocaleString();`.

Unfortunately, Google Chrome, Safari and Opera don’t play nice with this.  They just return the same as `toString()`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to type "in IE an Firefox" instead of "in IE and Javascript". I'll edit the answer when I get home.

Comment: And Opera (there's such a browser, yeah ;-) does not support this, AFAIR

Comment: @kirilloid: Thanks, I didn’t have time to test it with Opera. I’ve updated the answer to include that info.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [php.js](http://phpjs.org/pages/home) library?? [number_format()](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481) function.. the doc says that the function is standalone

=P i wont break my head to do something that's already done

Answer (score -1):

This one should work if you have restriction on using an array or regex.

```
function comma_separate(num) {
    var comma = Math.floor((num.length) / 3);
    var offset = (num.length) % 3;
    var result = '';
    if(offset > 0) {
        result = num.substr(0,offset);
    }

    for(var i=0; i<comma; i++) {
        result = result ? result + ',' : '';
        result = result + num.substr(i*3,3);
    }

    return result;
}
```

[tested here](http://jsfiddle.net/QHpQ3/)

Comment: Your function is significantly faster than all others =)

Comment: @kiriloid - thanks, I wasn't really aiming for fast(no benchmarks). Glad it turned out to be a good solution. It might be attributed to lack of array/regex use.