# Javascript Number formatting min/max decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I'm trying to create a function that can format a number with the minimum decimal places of 2 and a maximum of 4. So basically if I pass in 354545.33 I would get back 354,545.33 and if I pass in 54433.6559943 I would get back 54,433.6559.

```
function numberFormat(num){
    num = num+"";
    if (num.length > 0){

        num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g,'');
        num = Math.floor(num * 10000) / 10000;

        num += '';
        x = num.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;

    }
    else{
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: any good reason to do it with javascript?

Comment: @yoda – That is some peak SO answering right there!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### New 2016 solution

```
value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 4
});
```

Do not forget to include [polyfill](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/).

- [compat table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization)
- [API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

#### Old 2011 solution

To format a part, after decimal point you can use this:

```
value.toFixed(4).replace(/0{0,2}$/, "");
```

And for part before decimal point: [How to write this JS function in best(smartest) way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969823/how-to-write-this-js-function-in-bestsmartest-way)

Comment: I had a similar question of how to set a `max` number of decimals, but without requiring all `max` decimals to be present (the filler part of `toFixed()`). I came up with a solution based on your answer that I figured I'd share: `num.toFixed(max).replace(/\.?0+$/, '');`

Comment: @idolize solution is more complete, because it also removes the '.' if there are no decimal places left

Comment: Yes, but this certain question is about "with the **minimum** decimal places of 2 and a maximum of 4". Actually, it was more than 5 years ago. Now I'd advice using built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

`54433.6559943.toFixed(4)` will round to 4 places. You then  have to trim off up to two trailing zeroes.